# Running gulp produces no output

Tags: gulp

Just getting started with gulp, going through some tutorials. I'm in a mac terminal...

My extremely simple gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var scripts = 'scripts/*.js';

gulp.task('copy', function() {
  // place code for your default task here
  return gulp.src(scripts)
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});
```

I run 'gulp copy' on the command line and get some output that looks like it runs, but no files are copied:

```
Richards-MBP:gulp-test richardlovejoy$ gulp copy
[19:30:38] Using gulpfile /Work/gulp-test/gulpfile.js
[19:30:38] Starting 'copy'...
[19:30:38] Finished 'copy' after 27 ms
```

- I have 2 js files in the 'scripts' folder.
- I originally started with a more complex gulp file which also failed to produce any output.
- I inserted gulp-debug but it just shows me that 0 files are in the pipe.
- Running the latest version of node (5.2.0) as of this writing.
- Tried gulp --verbose but it gives me nothing.

How can I at least see what gulp is doing behind the scenes to debug this?

Thanks

Comment: What if you update your paths to relative paths? ./scripts/*.js and ./build/js?

Comment: I have the same problem. Seems like an issue with these build runners when "nothing happens" and you receive "no feedback" what's it's doing and what could be wrong.